# Find a path in oriented graph with cost divisible by N

Tags: algorithms, planar-graphs

Let's have a graph evaluated by integers, a number $N$, a stating node $S$ and a goal node $G$. The graph is a square mesh and all edges are oriented rightwards or downwards. Find a path form $S$ to $G$ which has a cost divisible by $N$. It doesn't have to be the shortest one. If more such paths exist, any can be taken as the result.

I'd like to know a polynomial algorithm which depends on the graph depth but not much on $N$ because $N$ can be really big.

**My attempt:**

It is enough to calculate only in $\Bbb{Z}_N$ while the result cost must be zero. Well, this helps a bit but it helps only a little if $N$ is big.

Scanning all possible paths from $S$ to $G$ is $O\bigl(2^d\bigr)$ hard where $d$ is the depth of goal.

My idea is dividing the graph into two parts, nodes closer to $S$ and nodes closer to $G$. Then I can search the graph from $S$ to the border and from $G$ to the border and compare the residuums. This is $O\bigl(2^{\frac{d}2}\bigr)$ hard.

Answer (score 1):

You can use dynamic programming for this. Algorithm:

1) find topological sorting of your nodes. Let's denote the sorted nodes as $v_0, v_1, ..., v_{n-1}$. Note that $S = v_0$ and $G = v_n$.

2) create a boolean DP table with two dimension: first dimension size $n$ and second dimension of size $N$. Initialize all values of the table to "false". Initialize DP[0][0] to "true". $$\text{DP-entry: DP[i][j] == "true" } \iff \text{there is a path from } v_0 \text{ to } v_i \text{ with cost } c \text{ such that } c =_N j $$

3) traverse the table in the following way:

`for i from 0 to n-1 do:
   for j from 0 to N-1 do:
     if(DP[i][j]) do:
       for every neighbour k of i:
         DP[k][j+cost(i, k)] = true;`

4) check whether DP[n][0] = true. If yes you can use backtracking to find a valid path.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Your algorithm works but the time increases by increasing $N$. If $N$ is big like $2^n$, it is almost as ineffective as evaluating all paths one by one. I worte it to my question.

Comment: Oh right. I just thought about using some kind of binary tree in every node to remember what values are reachable for this node (instead of an array). This would make the complexity independent of N for large N but I don't think it's better than $O(2^d)$. So that does not seem to be a solution either.